# How to get the all folder in text file after certain revision ID using batch script

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I want to get the all folder list into file after certain revID in SVN using Batch file.

currently I am using the command:

```
svn.exe list <URL> -R>test.txt
```

using this command I have getting all folder and file in text file. Have you any way to get the only folder after certain revision ID.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) to set new properties for each folder, for example : svn_folder

Then you can get all folder based on properties like this:

```
 svn.exe propget svn_folder <URL> -R>test.txt
```

I don't know if there is another better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Write in more free-form your requirements, if I translated they incorrectly, because "older list after certain revID in SVN" seems for me as white noise.

You want to get **repository tree at the state on revision N**? "After revision..." means "at the sate of any revision from N+1 to HEAD"

`svn ls -R [-v] -r N URL`, as written in `svn help ls`

Comment: ok... It is working, But we aslo want to print revno in file with folder path. is it possible?

Comment: @user1511510 `-v` option add author and last-rev columns to all objects in tree

Comment: when I have ran the command C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin>svn ls -R -v -r 1000 <url>>c:\abc\test.txt. Its generated output upto folder having 1000(revID). But we need above the 1000 revID folder.

Comment: @user1511510 - that is **in SVN terms** "folder above 100"??? I cant understand your needs (business-task), and yes - I know SVN

Comment: No... 1000 is revID. I want to get folder list having above the 1000 revID.

Comment: @user1511510 - OK, see at `svn ls -R -v URL`